# How to stop cortana/windows sports score notifications

Tags: windows-10, cortana

In the age where we can record all of our favorite teams, Microsoft has a "feature" that spoils all of the games the second I log on.

How is this "feature" disabled?

Comment: Turn off live tiles, if that's the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I have the exact opposite problem: I have zero interest in sports scores, so I find Cortana's "help" in this area equally annoying.

But I found the solution!

1. Press Windows Key + Q to open the Cortana Search bar/window
2. Look at the top left hand side. You should see a hamburger/settings icon (3 horizontal lines), a home icon (small house) and below that is a weird box with a circle in it. Click that one.
3. Welcome to Cortana's Notepad where topic settings are hidden. Ironically, you cannot use Cortana to search for this. Well done, Microsoft.
4. Select the "Manage Skills" tab and scroll down. You should see sports under the "Stay Up to Date" section. From there you can switch off some or all of the sports notifications.

Enjoy!

Comment: `Cortana's Notepad` or `Cortana's Notebook`.   `Manage Skills` is not displayed unless I use a profile connected to a Microsoft Account.  What versions of Windows does this answer apply to?

Answer (score 0):

Sports App -> Settings -> Notifications -> Off